# Python Flask send_file StringIO blank files

Tags: python, flask, stringio

I want to process a Pandas dataframe and send it to download as a CSV without a temp file. The best way to accomplish this I've seen is to use `StringIO`. Using the code below, a file downloads with the proper name, however the file is completely blank, and no error is shown. Why doesn't the file contain data?

```
@app.route('/test_download', methods = ['POST'])
def test_download():
    buffer = StringIO()
    buffer.write('Just some letters.')
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        buffer,
        as_attachment=True,
        download_name='a_file.txt',
        mimetype='text/csv'
    )
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The issue here is that in Python 3 you need to use `StringIO` with `csv.write` and `send_file` requires `BytesIO`, so you have to do both.

```
@app.route('/test_download')
def test_download():
    row = ['hello', 'world']
    proxy = io.StringIO()
    
    writer = csv.writer(proxy)
    writer.writerow(row)
    
    # Creating the byteIO object from the StringIO Object
    mem = io.BytesIO()
    mem.write(proxy.getvalue().encode())
    # seeking was necessary. Python 3.5.2, Flask 0.12.2
    mem.seek(0)
    proxy.close()

    return send_file(
        mem,
        as_attachment=True,
        download_name='test.csv',
        mimetype='text/csv'
    )
```

<sub>Prior to Flask 2.0, `download_name` was called `attachment_filename`.</sub>

Comment: What if I have a column with a value that I don't want to encode?

Comment: I'd doubt that the `proxy.close()` is really necessary. The `StringIO` obj vanishes at the end of the viewfunction execution anyway, doesn't it?

Answer (score 30):

Use `BytesIO` to write bytes.

```
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test_download', methods=['POST'])
def test_download():
    # Use BytesIO instead of StringIO here.
    buffer = BytesIO()
    buffer.write(b'Just some letters.')
    # Or you can encode it to bytes.
    # buffer.write('Just some letters.'.encode('utf-8'))
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        buffer,
        as_attachment=True,
        download_name='a_file.txt',
        mimetype='text/csv'
    )
```

<sub>Prior to Flask 2.0, `download_name` was called `attachment_filename`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

#### `make_response`

- To get Flask to download a **csv** file to the user, we pass a **csv** string to the `make_response` function, which returns a
  `Response` object.
- Then we add a **Header** which tells the browser to accept the file as a download.
- The **Mimetype** also must be set to `text/csv` in order to get the web browser to save it in something other than an **html** document.

```
from flask import Flask, make_response  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test_download', methods=['POST'])
def test_download():
    with StringIO() as buffer:
        # forming a StringIO object  
        buffer = StringIO()
        buffer.write('Just some letters.')
        # forming a Response object with Headers to return from flask 
        response = make_response(buffer.getvalue())
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=namaste.csv'
        response.mimetype = 'text/csv'
        # return the Response object
        return response
```

> **P.S.** It is preferred to use python's built-in `csv` library to deal with `csv` files

**References**

- https://matthewmoisen.com/blog/how-to-download-a-csv-file-in-flask/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringio-module-in-python/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Namaste

Answer (score 0):

if someone use python 2.7 with Flask and got the error about the module StringIO by importing it. This post can help you to solve your problem.

If you are importing String IO module, you can just change the import syntax by using this : **from io import StringIO** instead **from StringIO import StringIO**.

You can Also use **from io import BytesIO** if you are using image or some others ressource.

Thank you